# Problem installing windows application with wine

Tags: windows, wine

I tried to install windows application on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I run this command:

```
wine msiexec /i windows_app.msi
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
```

what is storage share mode, and how to set it up?